# Ember model finding records

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having trouble getting Ember's queryRecord to work properly. I'm trying to grab a site config from the server.

//app/routes/application.js

```
model: function(){
   return this.get('store').queryRecord('config',{}).then(function(config) {
    console.log(config.get('appname'));
  });
}
```

//app/adapters/config.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";
import ENV from './../config/environment';

export default DS.Adapter.extend({
  queryRecord(modelName, query) {
      return Ember.$.getJSON( ENV.APP.apiFull + 'config' );
  }
});
```

//app/serializers/applications.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function(attr, method) {
    return Ember.String.underscore(attr).toUpperCase();
  }
});
```

//JSON returning from server AJAX call

```
{"config":{"id":1,"environment": "development", "appname":"Sample App Name"}}
```

The console.log statement in //app/routes/application is returning undefined. This all seems to match up with the Ember documentation for version 2.9. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Side Note: Dont forget to return the result in model hook.

Comment: I added the return in the model hook, but the problem statement remains the same.

Comment: Ajax response looks REST format, so adapters/config.js file should extend `DS.RESTAdapter` -https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_queryRecord

Comment: extending `DS.Adapter` is fine, but interesting is what serializer is used.

Comment: I just added the serializer above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lux, thanks for pointing me towards the serializer. That led to me looking at the model member names and I found that I had underscored them in the model, but not in the JSON coming from the server.